# Getting different outputs with 'lsb_release -a' and 'uname -a'. Which is the correct Ubuntu version?

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, upgrade, dependencies

`lsb_release -a` returns 16.04.***3***:

```
# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

whereas `uname -a` returns 16.04.***2***

```
# uname -a
Linux u1b 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Which one is correct?

I believe this might be indicating a problem in my system, as when I do `apt-get -f install`, I get errors that say to the effect of "you have a higher version installed but I need a lower version", and vice versa:

```
# apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ghostscript:i386 : Depends: gsfonts:i386 (>= 6.0-1) but it is not installable
 ghostscript-dbg : Depends: libgs9 (= 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6) but 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.7 is installed or
                            ghostscript (= 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6) or
                            ghostcript-cups (= 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6) but it is not installable or
                            ghostcript-x (= 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6) but it is not installable
 libaudit1 : Breaks: libaudit1:i386 (!= 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1) but 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2 is installed
 libaudit1:i386 : Breaks: libaudit1 (!= 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2) but 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1 is installed
 libblkid1 : Breaks: libblkid1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is installed
 libblkid1:i386 : Breaks: libblkid1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libcupsfilters1 : Breaks: libcupsfilters1:i386 (!= 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.3) but 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 is installed
 libcupsfilters1:i386 : Breaks: libcupsfilters1 (!= 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) but 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.3 is installed
 libgs9 : Depends: libjbig2dec0 (>= 0.11) but it is not installed
 libgs9:i386 : Depends: libgs9-common:i386 (>= 9.18~dfsg~0) but it is not installable
 libmount1 : Breaks: libmount1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is installed
 libmount1:i386 : Breaks: libmount1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is installed
 libseccomp2 : Breaks: libseccomp2:i386 (!= 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1) but 2.2.3-3ubuntu3 is installed
 libseccomp2:i386 : Breaks: libseccomp2 (!= 2.2.3-3ubuntu3) but 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1 is installed
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is installed
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is installed
 systemd-shim:i386 : Depends: cgmanager:i386 (>= 0.32) but it is not installable
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

And if this is indeed a problem, how do I fix it?

**EDIT:** The output of `apt-cache policy ghostscript-dbg` is:

```
ghostscript-dbg:
  Installed: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6
  Candidate: 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.7
  Version table:
     9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.7 500
        500 http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.6 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2 500
        500 http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

The source is an ubuntu mirror I have set up. The `/etc/apt/sources.list` contains the following:

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted multiverse universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted multiverse universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted multiverse universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted multiverse universe
deb [arch=amd64] http://192.168.12.61/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted multiverse universe
```

**EDIT 2:** The out of `sudo apt install ghostscript-dbg=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.7`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ghostscript:i386 : Depends: gsfonts:i386 (>= 6.0-1) but it is not installable
 libaudit1 : Breaks: libaudit1:i386 (!= 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1) but 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
 libaudit1:i386 : Breaks: libaudit1 (!= 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2) but 1:2.4.5-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
 libblkid1 : Breaks: libblkid1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
 libblkid1:i386 : Breaks: libblkid1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
 libcupsfilters1 : Breaks: libcupsfilters1:i386 (!= 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.3) but 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
 libcupsfilters1:i386 : Breaks: libcupsfilters1 (!= 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.1) but 1.8.3-2ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
 libgs9 : Depends: libjbig2dec0 (>= 0.11) but it is not going to be installed
 libgs9:i386 : Depends: libgs9-common:i386 (>= 9.18~dfsg~0) but it is not installable
 libmount1 : Breaks: libmount1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
 libmount1:i386 : Breaks: libmount1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
 libseccomp2 : Breaks: libseccomp2:i386 (!= 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1) but 2.2.3-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libseccomp2:i386 : Breaks: libseccomp2 (!= 2.2.3-3ubuntu3) but 2.3.1-2.1ubuntu2~16.04.1 is to be installed
 libuuid1 : Breaks: libuuid1:i386 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3 is to be installed
 libuuid1:i386 : Breaks: libuuid1 (!= 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.3) but 2.27.1-6ubuntu3.4 is to be installed
 python : PreDepends: python-minimal (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is to be installed
          Depends: libpython-stdlib (= 2.7.11-1) but 2.7.12-1~16.04 is to be installed
 systemd-shim:i386 : Depends: cgmanager:i386 (>= 0.32) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Probably a problem with your sources. For example, what's the output of `apt-cache policy ghostscript-dbg`?

Comment: By the way, the discrepancy between `lsb_release` and `uname` is not the cause of your problem; it's a symptom, just like the errors on `apt-get -f install`.

Comment: @fkraiem I have edited the question details to include the contents of the `\etc\apt\sources.list` and the output of `apt-cache policy ghostscript-dbg`. And yeah, its a symptom, not cause.

Comment: For some reason, `ghostscript-dbg` is kept at an old version; let's find out why. Try `sudo apt install ghostscript-dbg=9.18~dfsg~0-0ubuntu2.7`.

Comment: It seems that many other packages are in a similar situation; this could be due to an issue with your local mirror.

Comment: @fkraiem It gives the same missing packages error (edit 2 in the question).

Comment: @fkraiem Could the issue with the sources be the fact that I specified `arch=amd64`, and it somehow needs `i386` files as well?

Comment: @fkraiem Any more help/suggestions?

Comment: Not really, your system seems to be in a very bad state. Try using an official mirror, for starters.

Comment: I got around the problem by using `apt-cacher` instead of `apt-mirror`. In `apt-cacher`, I don't need to keep a local repo, it just pulls packages through a proxy I had to set up, so no wastage of time in updating the repo over time.